# Дождать конца выполнения асинхронного метода,возвращающего void?

Tags: c#, async-await

Как сделать так,что бы `Task.FromResult` дождался конца выполнения операции `DownloadstringAsync`?

```
private void _webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The download has completed:");
        _html = e.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The download was canceled.");
        _html = "The download was canceled.";
    }
}


public async Task<string> DownloadAsync(string url, CancellationToken token)
{
    _webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/"));

    return await Task.FromResult(_html);
}
```

Comment: Никак, выносите в отдельный метод, возвращающий `Task`, а не `void`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не, тут просто смешение Task, и старого подхода когда есть запускающий метод и событие `...Completed`.

Comment: Возможно тебе поможет что-то вроде [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11883373/2881286) либо просто использовать вместо webclient класс который сразу работает с тасками

Comment: Смысл оборачивать асинхронную операцию в асинхронную операцию? Вам тут Task.Run() вообще не нужен.